# How to display text outside of the box of <div></div>

Tags: css, html

```
 <div class="signup">
    <div>Tenxian アカウントに必要な情報</div><br/>
    </div>
      <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>

     <div align="center">@2009 Tenxian      &nbsp;&nbsp;利用規約
    </div><br/>
    <div align="center"><a href="/en/bidding/index.php">Tenxian·English</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <a href="/cn/bid/index.php">腾闲·中国</a></div><br/><br/>
```

The code of .signup is:

```
.signup {
    border: 1px solid #99CCFF;
    position: absolute;
    width: 700px;
    height:450px;
    left: 50px;
    right: auto;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;

}
```

The problem is that

> @2009 Tenxian   利用規約
>
> Tenxian·English       腾闲·中国

is displayed in the box of `<div class="signup"></div>`, how to display it out of the box of `<div class="signup"></div>`?

I want to display

> @2009 Tenxian   利用規約
>
> Tenxian·English       腾闲·中国

at the bottom of a web page and outside of the box of `<div class="signup"></div>` . How to do it?

```
 <div style="position:relative"><div align="center" >@2009 Tenxian      &nbsp;&nbsp;利用規約
</div><br/>
<div align="center"><a href="/en/bidding/index.php">Tenxian·English</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <a href="/cn/bid/index.php">腾闲·中国</a></div><br/><br/>

</div>
```

does not work.

Comment: Do I have to write another CSS class to encompass @2009 Tenxian 利用規約

Tenxian·English 腾闲·中国 ?

Comment: Is there an easy way to do it?

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to simply move the Tenxian text outside of the div and into its own??

Comment: The Tenxian text is already outside of the .signup div, but when I browse it in a web browser, the Tenxian text is displayed in the box of the .signup div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your signup box is set to `position:absolute`. When you do this, the element is removed from the flow of the page.

The easiest solution is to simply not make it `position:absolute`. (If this is not possible, please revise your question so that more helpful answers can be posted.)

### Your original code, simplified

```
<div class="signup">
  <div>Tenxian アカウントに必要な情報</div>
</div>

<div class="footer">@2009 Tenxian 利用規約</div>
<div class="footer"><a href="/en/bidding/index.php">Tenxian·English</a> <a href="/cn/bid/index.php">腾闲·中国</a></div>
```

---

```
.footer {
  text-align: center;
}
```

---

Note that my solution below does NOT require you to use this code. It works fine with your existing HTML markup. I'm posting this code so that future readers will be able to understand the markup more easily.

### A possible solution

```
.signup {
  border: 1px solid #99CCFF;
  width: 700px;
  height: 450px;
  margin-left: 50px;
  margin-right: auto;
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 13px;
}
```

This makes your signup box take up the proper amount of space in the flow of the page. Here are the changes:

- Remove `position:absolute`: This causes the signup box to display as a regular statically positioned box
- Change `left` and `right` to `margin` instead: When a block-level box is displayed statically, it does is not affected by `top`, `left`, and so on. Instead, we use margins to push the box over to where we want it to be.

Answer (score 0):

`{overflow:visible;}` might work